# Illustrator blob brush automatically merge with path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

is there a way to make the result from the blob brush automatically merge with the path it intersects? I am working on a project and sometimes it automatically merges, and other times it doesn't. It seems to be random.

What are the prerequisite conditions necessary to ensure that it merges?

Answer (score 2):

**Double-click** the Blob Brush tool and change it's options.

[image]

Comment: I have tried that but I think if you play with those options a lot (esp with a touch surface) you will find that it does not always suffice. After hours of working it haphazardly I by some happenstance realized that if the current fill is a solid with no stroke AND *new art has basic appearance* is unchecked in the appearance panel, new blob brush strokes will *always* merge with intersecting layers with the same fill options.

Comment: The blob brush *only* works with stroke color. In fact, you *can't* use the blob brush tool *without* it applying a stroke color. If you set colors to no stroke and a fill, as soon as you let go of the mouse the color is moved to the stroke. -- I'm **not** claiming the settings are 100% intuitive. They are not. However with "Keep Selected" checked, anything with the blob brush *should* merge with all the current artwork. If you *also* check "Merge Only with Selection" then anything with the blob brush should only merge with the last blob brush stroke (and anything it merged with).

Comment: Also realize this isn't the Adobe help center... if you aren't happy with how things work, that's certainly not the fault of anyone at this web site. I was merely showing you *where* to alter the settings.